# get records matching with array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an array $arr = ["a","b"];
and table names **users**

```
| id | preferences |
| ---| ----------- |
| 1  | ["c","d"]   |
| 2  | ["a","b"]   |
| 3  | ["b","e"]   |
| 4  | ["a"]       |
| 5  | ["b"]       |
```

Now I'm trying get records with id 2,3,4,5

I tried below

```
$posts = User::select('id','preferences')->whereJsonContains('preferences', Arr::flatten(json_decode($arr)))->get();
```

But it returning only one row with id 2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On MySQL level you need in JSON_OVERLAPS. Look maybe your framework supports it.

Comment: Check out laravel `DB::raw` for implementing what @Akina suggested

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa yes. found the solution. thanks for suggetion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kinda known issue with `whereJsonContaints`, it can bug out very often. My workaround is actually using the DB facade instead of the Model query.

```
 DB::table('users')
            ->whereJsonContains('preferences', [$arr])
            ->get();
```

If that still does not work I think you can try (havent tested it)

```
DB::table('users')
            ->whereJsonContains('preferences', [$arr[0]])
            ->orWhereJsonContains('preferences', [$arr[1]])
            ->get();
```